# MSB3270: Mismatch between the processor architecture - Fakes Framework

Tags: .net, msbuild, compiler-warnings, microsoft-fakes

Since I use Fakes Framework in my UnitTest, I get the following MSBuild warning.

> warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "DocumentServiceModel", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. [C:\Projekte\XXX\XXX\XXX\Source\Testing\UT\XXX.UnitTest\obj\Debug\Fakes\ppsm\f.csproj]

The platform target of all projects in the solution is set to x86.

How can I get rid of this build warning?

**UPDATE1:**

I think the problem is, that the Fakes Framework creates a dynamic projekt with a platform target "Any CPU".

> (C:\Projekte\XXX\XXX\XXX\Source\Testing\UT\XXX.UnitTest\obj\Debug\Fakes\ppsm\f.csproj)

This dynamic project references the assemblies from my projekt, which runs with a platform target "x86".

I have no idea, how to change the dynamic Fakes projekt to "x86".

**UPDATE2:**

I created a sample project and I get the same warning:

```
Warning 1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "MSBErrorTest", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. [C:\Projekte\MSBErrorTest\UnitTestProject1\obj\Debug\Fakes\msbet\f.csproj] UnitTestProject1
```

UnitTest csproj:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <ProjectGuid>{4B14EC56-DDC7-4A16-92BA-2D2881E695D1}</ProjectGuid>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
        <RootNamespace>UnitTestProject1</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>UnitTestProject1</AssemblyName>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
        <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
        <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
        <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
        <ReferencePath>$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\$(VisualStudioVersion)\UITestExtensionPackages</ReferencePath>
        <IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
        <TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <Reference Include="MSBErrorTest.Fakes">
          <HintPath>FakesAssemblies\MSBErrorTest.Fakes.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="System" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Choose>
        <When Condition="('$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '') and '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.5'">
          <ItemGroup>
            <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
          </ItemGroup>
        </When>
        <Otherwise>
          <ItemGroup>
            <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" />
          </ItemGroup>
        </Otherwise>
      </Choose>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="UnitTest1.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MSBErrorTest\MSBErrorTest.csproj">
          <Project>{f1ae6c89-6f6a-404e-b9e2-10ee2f66942f}</Project>
          <Name>MSBErrorTest</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Fakes Include="Fakes\MSBErrorTest.fakes" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Choose>
        <When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' And '$(IsCodedUITest)' == 'True'">
          <ItemGroup>
            <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
              <Private>False</Private>
            </Reference>
            <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
              <Private>False</Private>
            </Reference>
            <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
              <Private>False</Private>
            </Reference>
            <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
              <Private>False</Private>
            </Reference>
          </ItemGroup>
        </When>
      </Choose>
      <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets')" />
      <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
      <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
           Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
      <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      </Target>
      <Target Name="AfterBuild">
      </Target>
      -->
    </Project>
```

ClassLib csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{F1AE6C89-6F6A-404E-B9E2-10EE2F66942F}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>MSBErrorTest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MSBErrorTest</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

**UPDATE3:**

I changed my config to look like this.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But I still get the warning

Comment: See my updated answer below to force target platform of your project to use x86.

Comment: I changed this already, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Hmm.... what is your project template type?

Comment: Visual C# - Unit Test Project - .NET 4.5

Comment: Have you updated your VS 2012 to have Update 3 installed?

Comment: Yes, we use VS2012 Premium Update 3

Comment: Wow... This is so confusing. I believe that there are some difference in settings. I have tried VM to install VS 2012 Premium Update 3 and I also have no problems, not just in my main VS 2012 Ultimate Update 3 machine. Could you post your csproj file?

Comment: I have create a sample project and update the post the csproj files

Comment: There, I have updated my answer based on your question update.

Comment: I changed the config like you said. But I still get the warning.

Comment: have you changed the debug and release configuration?

Comment: yes, I have changed both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have got a response from Microsoft for this issue

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804933/msb3270-mismatch-between-the-processor-architecture-fakes-framework

**Visual Studio 2012:**

> Create the following element in “Fakes\MSBErrorTestClass.fakes” file
> under 'Fakes' node:

```
<Compilation>
 <Property Name="PlatformTarget">x86</Property>
</Compilation>
```

**Visual Studio 2013:**

This issue has been fixed in the latest release i.e. Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Brilliant... Was facing the same issue and usual answer was to change the Solution/Project settings. Fakes setting did the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: When I used this, I put the text in this answer in my fakes file at the top just inside the fakes part and it complained that it was expecting an assembly entry.  I moved it to the bottom of the file and everything worked great.  Thanks for the answer, I have been fighting this for a long time.

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm getting this error only for Fakes assemblies that I will only be running unit tests on, I decided to just ignore this error.  This can be accomplished by adding this to your Fakes XML:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="FakedAssemblyName.dll"/>
  <Compilation>
    <Property Name="ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch">None</Property>
  </Compilation>
</Fakes>
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you use 3rd party libraries? If you use them, check them to see if they use the same x86 as the target processor.
It is clear that the targeted processor should be the same for all of the references, not just the target of your project.

UPDATE: Apparently this guy from Microsoft is experiencing this also. You can try to use his workaround:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/05/03/10300809.aspx

From the blog entry, do this:
Search for this "**PlatformTarget**" in your csproj file, and edit it to match this:

```
<PlatformTarget Condition=" '$(PlatformTarget)' == '' ">x86</PlatformTarget>
```

Let me know if this solve your problem.

UPDATE 2: Based on your source code of the unittest.csproj and the classlib.csproj, the configuration is still based on "AnyCPU".

Please look for this line:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
```

And also this line:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
```

Those target platform should also be set to use x86.

The easier way is by setting the Debug and Release by clicking "Configuration Manager..." at "Debug" combobox on Visual Studio toolbar, like in this rough illustration:

[image: Visual Studio 2012 Debug/Release]

Comment: Yes, we use 3rd party libraries. But they seems to be ok. It starts as soon as I use Fakes Framework. Without Fakes Framework all is fine!

Comment: Fake Framework requires you to target all of the references to use x86. Have you checked your 3rd party libraries target?

Comment: I just deleted all 3rd party libraries for one project. But the warning is still there.

Comment: are you using VS 2012 Beta or Preview? If you are using it, try to reinstall VS 2012 RTM.

Comment: We are using VS2012 Premium Update 3

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with other possible workaround. Could you try it and let me know the result?

Comment: Thanks, I tried a few things similar to the msdn post, but without success.

Comment: I have Edit my question with some new findings.

Answer (score 0):

In *project_name*.csproj file remove `ItemGroup` node where is set processorArchitecture attribute. It sth like;

`<ItemGroup>
    <Reference ... , processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    ...
</ItemGroup>`

That helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that landed here and has nothing to do with "Fakes", check for warnings / errors in your [References](https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/troubleshooting-guide/visual-studio-tg/missing-assembly-references). I found a *ghost* DLL that fortunately the project did not require, and removed it. Worked great!