# VS2013 - MSB3270: Mismatch between the processor architecture - Fakes Framework

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings, microsoft-fakes

In the same vein as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833006/msb3270-mismatch-between-the-processor-architecture-fakes-framework), I'm seeing a build warning when building the test assemblies in my cloud project that use the Visual Studio Fakes framework.

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "msshrtmi", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. [D:\SSO\Shared\obj\Main\ServicesShared.Tests\Fakes\msss\f.csproj]

The only difference is that I've only begun to see this problem **after** upgrading to VS 2013. According to [this connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804933/msb3270-mismatch-between-the-processor-architecture-fakes-framework) it should be fixed. I tried to apply the VS 2012 workaround, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Has anyone else encountered this with VS 2013 and/or how have you been able to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following inside .fakes xml file (located under Fakes folder in the project tree)

---

```
<Compilation>
    <Property Name="PlatformTarget">x64</Property>
</Compilation>
```

---

Comment: This worked for me -- but I also had to change the platform target of my test assembly (which, in the OP's case, is ServicesShared.Tests).  I also had to Clean and Rebuild the solution.